# Selecting multiple maximum rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL table named `Domain`. How can I find the most popular email domain from this table. Directly I want to find all rows with the maximum count.

```
Domain    
gmail.com    
gmail.com    
gmail.com    
yahoo.com    
yahoo.com    
yahoo.com    
rediffmail.com    
rediffmail.com
mail.com
```

My desired output:

```
Domain      No_of_users
gmail.com   3
yahoo.com   3
```

Comment: The records that are most used. So gmail and yahoo both 3 times, but not rediffmail, because it is used less than 3 times.

Comment: @user1690831, I added a little bit more example data to stop the confusion that's going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  x.Domain,
  x.No_of_users
from
  (select
    d.Domain, 
    count(d.Domain) as No_of_users
  from
    Domain d
  group by 
    d.Domain) x
where
  x.No_of_users = 
    (select
      max(x2.No_of_users)
    from
      (select
         d2.Domain,
         count(d2.Domain) as No_of_users
      from
         Domain d2
      group by 
        d2.Domain) x2)
```

Comment: Too complicated. @Marlin's answer does the same without so many subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Domain, count(id)
FROM Domain
GROUP BY Domain.Domain
HAVING count(id) = (SELECT count(id) FROM Domain D GROUP BY D.Domain ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 1)
```