# substring_index function does not exist error

Tags: mysql, rows

I have a table named 'data' which stores the email addresses and city of users and I want to find the most popular email domain. I use the following query to to find the rows which have maximum value.
exapmple for my table:

```
Email           Name        City
dsmks@gmail.com     John    California
sak@gmail.com       Leo sydney
dsnk@gmail.com      Ross    NY
askd@yahoo.com      Ronny   Canberra
ajs@yahoo.com       Monty   London
kasl@yahoo.com      Jim washington
uy@hotmail.com      Finn    Las vegas
```

I have computed the answer using this query

```
  select  x.city, x.No_of_People from (select e.city, count(e.city) as No_of_People from data e group by  e.city) x
where  x.No_of_People = (select max(x2.No_of_People) from (select e2.city, count(e2.city) as No_of_People from data e2 group by         e2.city) x2)
```

But i don't wan't to use limits as it does not return multiple rows. So I have used the following query using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543723/selecting-multiple-maximum-rows)

```
    select
  x.substring_index (email,'@',-1),
  x.No_of_Users
from
  (select
    e.substring_index (email,'@',-1), 
    count(e.substring_index (email,'@',-1)) as No_of_Users
  from
    data e
  group by 
    e.substring_index (email,'@',-1)) x
where
  x.No_of_Users = 
    (select
      max(x2.No_of_Users)
    from
      (select
         e2.substring_index (email,'@',-1),
         count(e2.substring_index (email,'@',-1)) as No_of_Users
      from
         data e2
      group by 
        e2.substring_index (email,'@',-1)) x2)
```

The query that i'm using is giving this error "FUNCTION e2.substring_index does not exist". help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for using the function.  The alias goes on the column, not the function.  For instance, your last subquery should use this syntax:

```
  from (select substring_index(e2.email,'@',-1) as strind,
               count(substring_index(e2.email,'@',-1)) as No_of_Users
        from data e2
        group by substring_index (e2.email,'@',-1)
       ) x2
```

I also named the first column, so you can refer to it outside the subquery if you want.

To count the number of occurrences in a string, use this trick:

```
(length(e2.email) - length(replace(e2.email, '@', '')) as numAmpersands
```

Comment: yeah man. you'are correct. My syntax is totally illogical. Thanks, You saved my time.

Comment: Hey..Please tell one more thing. I have corrected the syntax and it is giving correct answer. I mean it is displaying the correct count of number of email domains. But the second line of code is not working.
select
  substring_index(x.email,'@',-1),
  x.No_of_Users
from...............
The error is "Unknown column 'x.email' in 'field list"
if i remove this line,'substring_index(x.email,'@',-1)', then it works. But i need to show the domain name also.

Comment: Is there any error in the above statement 'substring_index(x.email,'@',-1)'. how can i display the name??????

Comment: @user1690831 . . . You should ask another question on the best way to get the information that you want.  This question was quite specific on the substring_index function.